# Possible to update trial version of Visual Studio 2015 to the Open Licence version my company just bought?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Already have VS 2015 Pro Trial installed.  My company is a registered charity and has downloaded the Open Licence version for me to install, but as the installed one has updated itself now, it says the version installed is newer than the one on the DVD so I cannot run update/reinstall.

I have lots of plugins/settings already in place that I don't want to lose by removing/reinstalling if it's possible to do an in-place update of some sort?

Comment: There are no different versions AFAIK (as in binaries). What are the instructions on how to activate the Open License version?

Comment: "Open License version " - You mean Visual Studio 2015 Community, if so, they are entirely separate licenses and installations.  If you don't mean Visual Studio 2015 Community you have to be more specific.

Comment: It's an "open licence" product that doesn't need a key when installing according to the maintenance guy here.  It's always worked in the past.

He managed to get a key generated from our MS account somehow and that's worked, so problem solved a different way, basically.

Comment: @TheMook You should ask "the maintenance guy" for the specifics and then post an answer here to help others who may come along (and to earn some rep ;) ).

Comment: Apparently the Open Licence Portal allows you to generate a key, which is what he did.